# Identity Toolkit API for android

Tags: android, api, exception

Im trying to execute the Android Identity Toolkit example from Google: https://github.com/googlesamples/identity-toolkit-android .

But, when I tried to execute the tutorial it gives me the next stack trace:

```
06-17 12:04:00.450  12306-12339/com.google.identitytoolkit.demo E/GoogleIdpClient﹕ Unrecoverable auth exception: Unknown
com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown
        at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.identitytoolkit.idp.google.GoogleIdpClient$1.call(GoogleIdpClient.java:126)
        at com.google.identitytoolkit.idp.google.GoogleIdpClient$1.call(GoogleIdpClient.java:120)
        at com.google.identitytoolkit.executor.ProgressRequestExecutor$2.doInBackground(ProgressRequestExecutor.java:84)
        at com.google.identitytoolkit.executor.ProgressRequestExecutor$2.doInBackground(ProgressRequestExecutor.java:71)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)  


06-17 12:04:00.475  12306-12306/com.google.identitytoolkit.demo E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
```

I tried to find some iformation about that exception, but I cant find anything clear, or anything I can use as a solution.

I did all the steps which Google say to do: https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/android/quickstart but still not working, probally I did something wrong. Can you help me?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this issue? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: I didn't, sorry. I adapted Facebook and Google+ API's to my application.

I think it was an error on Identity Toolkit Facebook compatibility: Facebook SDK changes so much in the last months, and Identity Toolkit developers didn't fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I think, a lot can trigger the exception with so much configuring going on. I got the same exception. For me, the issue is in the AndroidManifest(I got everything right in the developer console configuration).

My first mistake:
android:scheme is given "Client ID for Android" instead of "Client ID for web application"

My next mistake: (I think this one is really causing the unknown exception)
identitytoolkit.server_client_id is given "Key for web applications" instead of, again, "Client ID for web application"(this time without modifying reverse like above)